# How to set CircleCI to run automatically AFTER a push to heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, github, circleci

I need to run an automated scenario after every time I push to Heroku or to
git-origin. I was recommended to use CircleCI.
I deployed CircleCI and it runs to scenario every time I commit and push a file in the automation repository, but I need to configure it to run after I push to Heroku or git-origin from the actual site repository.

I read the documentation of CircleCI and I saw a functionality that allows you to push to Heroku after you run tests successfully, but it's not good enough.

Can anyone advice me (or give an example) to first, how to change the automation from running after a automation-repository-push to other-repository-push, and second, how to tell CircleCI to run AFTER a heroku-push and after a 
git-origin-push?

Comment: Seems like you are missing the point of setting up Continuous Integration with CircleCI (or any other service). The idea is to automatically run the tests with a CI server BEFORE deploying the code to production. The code should not get deployed to production if the tests fail.

Comment: I do get it, but I don't want to deploy the code every single time the tests pass. It takes long time and we commit files many times a day. I want to push to heroku when I have to and then run a scenario that creates stuff in my system after I restored the heroku db.

Comment: @PrakashMurthy (forgot to tag)

Comment: You should be looking at Git hooks; not circle CI.

Comment: @PrakashMurthy How can I run "xyz.feature" file from repository A when I push to heroku-remote or origin-remote in repository B?

Comment: @PrakashMurthy The more I read about git hooks the more I realize it is impossible to run automation from repository A when pushing code in repository B. Do you have a solution? Is it possible with git hooks or do you know some other system that does it? Maybe I can send a deploy hook from heroku to trigger them?